# pyspark - Read files with custom delimiter to RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, bigdata

I am newbie in pyspark, and I'm trying to read and merge RDD rows into one row.

Assuming that I have the following text file:

```
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2 D3
A3 X1 YY1
DELIMITER_ROW
Z1 B1 C1 Z4
X2 V2 XC2 D3
DELIMITER_ROW
T1 R1
M2 MB2 NC2
S3 BB1 
AQ3 Q1 P1"
```

Now, I want to combine all rows appears in each section (between DELIMITER_ROW) into one row, and return a list of these merged rows.

I want to create this kind of list:

```
[[A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2 D3 A3 X1 YY1]
 [Z1 B1 C1 Z4 X2 V2 XC2 D3]
 [T1 R1 M2 MB2 NC2 S3 BB1 AQ3 Q1 P1]]
```

How can It be done in pyspark using RDD?

For now I know how to read the file and filter out the delimiter rows:

```
sc.textFile(pathToFile).filter(lambda line: DELIMITER_ROW not in line).collect()
```

but I don't know how to reduce/merge/combine/group the rows in each section into one row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than reading and splitting, You can use `hadoopConfiguration.set` to set the delimiter which separates the row and then split the row.

`spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "DELIMITER_ROW")`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, It was helpful.
In pyspark (using zeppelin) I write:


conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "DELIMITER_ROW")
....MY CODE
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n")